# postgres user doesn't work after Migration Assistant to new mac

Tags: macos, postgresql, psql

I got a new mac today and ran the migration assistant which worked great for most things, however I can't seem to get into psql now.

postgres is installed with homebrew and the service starts fine, however whenever I run 'psql postgres' now I get the following error:

```
psql: FATAL:  role "Jamie" does not exist
```

Jamie being my actual account name for the user on my mac. This was all working/running absolutely fine on my old mac...

Comment: Also, if I try and create the postgres user manually, I get a similar error:

createuser: could not connect to database postgres: FATAL:  role "Jamie" does not exist

Comment: And for "psql -U postgres" I get "psql: FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, local account name was different what was showing based on my old mac configuration. Painful. Changed to connect to psql with different user and it worked fine.